# How to use AND and OR operator with IF in power automate desktop?

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I searched and I found someone say it can be used like this:

```
IF $'''%TotalList = 200% || %TotalList = 400% || %TotalList = 600%''' = True THEN
```

[image]

But after I try it the flow was just skipped this if line so how I should use the two operands ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it all between a single set of % % and use OR instead of ||.

```
%TotalList = 200 OR TotalList = 400 OR TotalList = 600%
```

The microsoft [documentation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/variable-manipulation#logical-operators)